# Pandas + matplotlib: changing date tick formats

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

Pandas has the convenient pandas.DataFrame.plot functionality, which will plot all the columns of a DataFrame using Matplotlib. I often find myself using a DatetimeIndex, so the resulting plots share the same datetime x-axis. However, I also often want to use the Matplotlib DateFormatter to format the tick labels on the resulting plots. It appears that is out of the question though...

To show my problem, a little example code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 11))
# Create DataFrame with random data
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": np.random.random(100), "bar": np.random.random(100)},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", freq="D", periods=100))

# First method
df.plot(ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title("df.plot()")

# Second method
df.plot(ax=ax[1])
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
ax[1].set_title('ax = df.plot(); ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))')

# Third method
ax[2].plot_date(df.index, df["foo"].values, fmt="-", label="foo")
ax[2].plot_date(df.index, df["bar"].values, fmt="-", label="bar")
pd.DatetimeIndex
ax[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
ax[2].set_title('ax.plot_date(df.index, df["foo"]); ax.plot_date(df.index, df["bar"])\nax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))')
ax[2].legend()

# Rotate ticklabels in all plots
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.tick_params(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

results in the following plots:
[image]

As you can see, the minor tick locations on the first plot aren't perfect, but the date notation is at least correct.

In the second plot, I tried to use the matplotlib DateFormatter to gain a bit more control over how the dates are actually displayed, but the noted dates are completely wrong. Furthermore, using %y instead of %Y will throw an error on my Windows machine, since the year needs to be > 1900.

In the third plot, I skipped the Pandas built-in plotting functionality, and went straight for Matplotlib, using exactly the same technique to format my date tick labels. This does exactly what I wanted it to do, with the proper dates displayed in my own defined way.

I've also already tried converting the DataFrame's index to various datetime times, using pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime and pandas.Timestamp's to_pydatetime, to_datetime64, to_numpy, and to_julian_date functions, but to no avail.

Is it possible at all to control how the Pandas plotting notates the datetime values of a DatetimeIndex? Or am I stuck with manually creating the plots using Matplotlib?

Basically: can I get the result of the third plot, using pd.DataFrame.plot() instead of plt.plot_date()?

Comment: `df.plot` is just a convenient function to plot a DataFrame. It returns an `Axes` object which you can modify to your wish: `ax[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: what exactly do you want you question is a bit not so clear !!!

Comment: @CodeDifferent As you can see in my example, that doesn't work...